# Sequelize query call procedure firing twice

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Calling procedure in Sequelize query resulting two times.

```
return await sequelize.query('CALL get_products();', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

// In route

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  let router = require('express').Router();

  const verifyToken       = require('../../middlewares/verifyToken');
  const productController = require('../../controllers/api/productController');

  router.get('/products', verifyToken, productController.getProducts);
  router.get('/products/:productId', verifyToken, productController.getProduct);

  app.use('/api', router);
};
```

// productController.js

```
const db        = require('../../models');
const Product   = db.products;
const sequelize = db.sequelize;


 exports.getProducts = async (request, response) => {
  let responseData = {};
  let products     = [];

  // Get products
  products = await sequelize.query('CALL get_products();')
  .then(data => {
    return data;  
  })
  .catch(error => {
    //  
  });
  //-------------

 // Set response data
 if (products) {
  responseData = {
    status: true,
    message: 'Products found.',
    data: {
      products: products
    }
  };
} else {
  responseData = {
    status: false,
    message: 'Products not found.',
    data: null
  };
}
//------------------

return response.status(200).json(responseData);
```

console.log firing twice in the function even if the query code removed. looks like this is a code error of mine.

Comment: Could you please add more details about this? What's the context you call the procedure? What's the content of the procedure?

Comment: @oniramarf This query is set in the procedure.

SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(color)) FROM tbl_products AS c WHERE c.style_number = p.style_number) AS color_count, MIN(wholesale_price_a) AS min_price, MAX(wholesale_price_a) AS max_price FROM tbl_products AS p GROUP BY style_number

Comment: Ok. What about the context where you call the procedure. So far I can't understand why it's executed 2 times. Just edit your post with all the additional details.

Comment: check this CALL get_products();  function. maybe you return value this function.

Comment: @NitinSinghNaruka sends you all code. means we need to understand the issue.

Comment: @oniramarf I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in having both `await` and `.then(...).catch(...)`.

You should use just one of these two constructs, depending on your preference.

**Here with .then().catch()**

```
const db        = require('../../models');
const Product   = db.products;
const sequelize = db.sequelize;


exports.getProducts = (request, response) => {
  let responseData = {};
  let products     = [];

  // Get products
  products = await sequelize.query('CALL get_products();').then(data => {
    // Set response data
    if (products) {
      responseData = {
        status: true,
        message: 'Products found.',
        data: {
          products: products
        }
      };
    } else {
      responseData = {
        status: false,
        message: 'Products not found.',
        data: null
      };
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    // handle any error
  });      
}
```

**Here with await**

```
const db        = require('../../models');
const Product   = db.products;
const sequelize = db.sequelize;


exports.getProducts = async (request, response) => {
  let responseData = {};
  let products     = [];

  // Get products
  products = await sequelize.query('CALL get_products();');

  // Set response data
  if (products) {
    responseData = {
      status: true,
      message: 'Products found.',
      data: {
        products: products
      }
    };
  } else {
    responseData = {
      status: false,
      message: 'Products not found.',
      data: null
    };
  }
}
```

I always prefer using `.then().catch()` syntax so I don't really know how to handle any error with the `await` pattern. Maybe a try-catch could do. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you... I will do it with one pattern.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong that would cause a double execution of the procedure. And actually the double pattern won't cause the double execution, just handling two times the same result.